# Java vs native coding in Android Application development

Tags: java, android, c++

I plan to create an SDK (involving huge data manipulations), which can used to create applications on Android.

I plan to develop the complete SDK, including the libraries in Java, for the reason that if I implement my libraries in the native language(C++) the data movement between the Java and the native layer will involve memory copies and will make my application look slow.

I plan to port the same SDK later to other platforms like Windows Mobile. I am a bit confused on the better approach to code in such cases, keeping in mind the portability and performance of the SDK.

Inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you plaining to create a real SDK like the one already provided by Google or do you want to create a Framework which should then be ported to other platforms (like a Game-Engine for example)?

Comment: I want to create a framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Mobile supports native code (Visual C++, see [Getting Started in Developing Applications for Windows Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158522.aspx)) so using the Android NDK would be a good option. At least you wouldn't have to write the whole thing from scratch. You could have the common code base written in C/C++ and only write the Java wrappers for Android.

As you know, Windows Phone 7 (the successor to Windows Mobile) uses C# and whatever approach you take on Android, you'd need to rewrite the SDK from scratch anyway. Windows Phone 7.x *might* be supporting native code (C/C++) sometime in the future but not anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the portability. Could you comment on performance in terms of java and native coding in android?

Comment: From [http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html): "Using native code does not result in an automatic performance increase, but always increases application complexity." So if you're not having performance issues using only Java, you don't _need_ native code. If portability is a major concern, native code could be ported to, for example, iOS relatively easily, just replace the Java wrappers with Objective C/C++ wrappers.